# In jQuery, how do you use 'this' properly in this situation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am confused on why this code is written like this, but I am sure it is important to understand:

```
$.fn.mapImage = function(options){
    //Set user input options and defaults
    var optionConfig = $.extend({}, $.fn.mapImage.defaults, options);

    image=this;
    this.image = this;

    // Assign defaults
    this.getUrl = optionConfig.getUrl;
    this.saveUrl = optionConfig.saveUrl;
    this.deleteUrl = optionConfig.deleteUrl;
    this.editable = optionConfig.editable;
    this.pinpoints = optionConfig.pinpoints;
    image.pinpoints = optionConfig.pinpoints;
    image.pinpointCount = 0;


    this.canvas = $('<div class="canvas"><div class="create-mode"></div><div class="edit-mode"></div></div>');
    this.image.after(this.canvas);
    this.canvas.height(this.height());
    this.canvas.width(this.width());
    this.canvas.css('background-image', 'url("' + this.attr('src') + '")');
    this.canvas.children('.create-mode').css('cursor', 'crosshair');
    this.canvas.children('.create-mode, .edit-mode').height(this.height());
    this.canvas.children('.create-mode, .edit-mode').width(this.width());
    this.canvas.children('.edit-mode').show();
    this.canvas.children('.create-mode').hide();
    $(this).hide();


}
```

What I dont understand is why does the code have `image=this` and `this.image=this`, is it the same thing? why not do something like `image.after(this.canvas)`  does this `this` refer to the current object that is passed through the function in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this is confusing (no pun intended) is because you are missing a bit of code for the example above to make sense:

```
var image; // necessary otherwise you'll get a runtime exception.

$.fn.mapImage = function(options){
    //Set user input options and defaults
    var optionConfig = $.extend({}, $.fn.mapImage.defaults, options);

    image=this;
    this.image = this
    ...
```

Now, when you look at:

```
image=this;
this.image = this
```

It makes more sense doesn't it? The first assignment is for the local variable '`var image`'. That way, a reference is kept even when the function has finished executing.

The second assignment is for a property of the current object, denominated by '`this`'.

Here's your explanation, but to me there is no point of using both `this.image` and `image` in the code. Just using `image` would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

> What I dont understand is why does the
>   code have `image=this` and
>   `this.image=this`, is it the same thing?

no, they are not...

```
image = this;
this.image = this;
```

in that we can say that `image` and `this.image` are referring to same thing `this`, right?

```
image = this;
// ^      ^----- current object
// | --- this image is a variable
this.image = this;
//     ^--- this image is a property of current object, this 
// because of image = this;, we can also say that
image.image = this;
// ^    ^      ^----- current object
// |    |------------ property
// |----------------- variable
```

you can also get some [idea here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192328/how-does-the-this-syntax-work/3192361#3192361)

Comment: that is a really obscure answer

Comment: The use of the word "this" in the comments makes the explanation really confusing since you're trying to explain the keyword this. I kno what you mean but for someone trying to figure it, i reckon that would just be confusing..