# How does the "this" syntax work?

Tags: jquery

Is this line

```
$(this).attr("id").replace("_button","");
```

equivalent to this one?

```
this.attr("id").replace("_button","");
```

Comment: More context on this code would be helpful. I left an answer but I made some assumptions that could be wrong based on where this came from.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

since `this` always contains a reference to the `object of invocation`, it really depends **where** you call that code.

If you call this within a `jQuery event handler`, `this` is a reference to the `DOM element` itself, so you need to translate it into a jQuery object by calling `$()` before you can call jQuery methods on it. That in turn means

```
this.attr("id").replace("_button","");
```

will not work there.

If you're writting a plugin method for instance, `this` already **IS** a `jQuery object` (`reference`) and both lines would actually do the same. Of course, if `this` already is a `jQuery object` you doing extra work, trying to parse it again.

example:

```
$.fn.yourplugin = function(){
     // this refers to a jQuery object
     return this.each(function(i,v){
     });
});
```

Comment: +1 for having almost the exact same thoughts here :p (copy paste :D) (and I like *object of invocation* )

Comment: I just realized that crockford is right, he mentioned somewhere that it's hard to talk about `this`. "If you call this" is trouble for a reader already.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the context, but probably not.

If you have an event handler, say:

```
$('#_button_foo').click(function() {
     $(this).attr("id").replace("_button","");
});
```

Then `this` will refer to the **DOM element** whereas `$(this)` creates a jQuery object and let you call jQuery functions on this object.

---

On the other side, if you develop a plugin and have

```
jQuery.fn.plugin = function() {
     this.each(function() {...});
}
```

then `this` refers to the jQuery object you call the method on.

Answer (score 2):

`this` refers to the object it is used in. In the global scope it refers to `window` and in a method call it refers to the object the method is called on.

In your case `this` will probably refer to an element in the DOM that is fetched with some other jQuery mechanism like an event ([`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/), [`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), etc.) or an iteration over a list of elements (like [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)). In that case you only get that DOM element but not a jQuery object with the extension of jQuery methods like `attr`. So you need to turn it into an jQuery object using the `$` constructor function.

Answer (score 1):

The $(this) will turn the DOM Object into a jQuery object, so you can use the jQuery functions.

So `$(this)` and `this` are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, the keyword '`this`' refers to the object whose context you're in.  So if you're calling `myObj.method1()`, then inside method1's code, '`this`' would refer to `myObj`.

In jQuery, most operations return a jQuery result set object, often called a jQuery wrapper.  For example, the selector `$("a")` would return a jQuery result set that contains all the `<a>` DOM elements.  `$("a").get(0)` would return the first anchor DOM element, `$("a").get(1)` would return the second anchor, etc.

So `$(this)` refers to the jQuery wrapper object, and `this` refers to the DOM element.

So to sum it all up: `$(this).get(0)` would be the same as `this`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which context you are using it.

`$(this)` is a jQuery object and `this` is a DOM object.

So, they are not same.

If you are developing jquery plugin then `this` is same as `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

No. It sounds like you are in the context of a closure used for a jquery method. Within the function it points to the current DOM object therefore jquery functions wouldn't be possible. That is why it is wrapped with the jquery function to get that object.

Answer (score 0):

`this` always refers to the object that the current function is a member of. If the function is global, that's usually the `window` object, at least if you're in a web browser.

`$(this)` is actually `$()` (the main jQuery function) called with the before mentioned `this` as a parameter. It wraps `this` into a jquery object that offers all the jQuery methods. These methods are notavailable on just `this`.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's not.

You can use this.id.replace("_button","") instead.